# Using Assuming for conditional expression in Solve

Tags: equation-solving, assumptions, constraint

When I solve the following equation I obtain a solution with a conditional expression

```
Solve[{0 == k Sin[x - y] - Sin[x], 0 == k Sin[y - x] - Sin[y]}, {x,y}]
```

How can I find the specific solutions in the range $0<x\leq2\pi$ and $-2 \pi<y\leq0$.

I'm trying to use assuming, but with no success

```
 Assuming[
   {0 <= x <= 2 π, -2 π <= y <= 0},
   Solve[
      {
        0 == k Sin[x - y] - Sin[x], 
        0 == k Sin[y - x] - Sin[y]
      }
      , {x,y}
    ]
   ]
```

Comment: This may help `Sin[y - x] // TrigExpand`

Comment: @kglr, your suggestion does not help

Comment: The assumptions in `Assuming` or `$Assumptions` are only used by functions that use the option `Assumptions` (e.g., `Simplify`, `FullSimplify`, `Refine`, `Integrate`). With functions such as `Solve`, `NSolve`, `Reduce`, or `Minimize`, the "assumptions" can be entered as "constraints" as part of the system of equations, inequations, inequalities, domain specifications, domain specifications, or quantifiers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
sol = Simplify@Solve[
   {
    0 == k Sin[x - y] - Sin[x],
    0 == k Sin[y - x] - Sin[y],
    0 <= x <= 2 π,
    -2 π <= y <= 0
    }
   , {x, y}
   , Reals
   , Method -> Reduce
   ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
Manipulate[
 Module[
  {
   points = With[{k = k}, Evaluate@sol[[All, All, 2]]]
   },
  Column[
   {
    Row[{"k = ", k}],
    TableForm@points,
    Show[
     Plot3D[{
       k Sin[x - y] - Sin[x],
       k Sin[y - x] - Sin[y]
       }
      , {x, 0, 2 π}
      , {y, -2 π, 0}
      ],
     Graphics3D[
       {
        Red,
        PointSize[Large],
        Point[
          {
           Sequence @@ #, 0} & /@ (
              points /. {Undefined, Undefined} -> Nothing
               )
              ]
          }
         ]
     ]
    }]
  ]
 , {k, 0, 2, 0.1}
 ]
```

[image]

Comment: Also look at using `FullSimplify` vice `Simplify` for reduced `LeafCount`

Answer (score 1):

```
Sin[x-y] // TrigExpand
```

> Cos[y] Sin[x] - Cos[x] Sin[y]

```
Reduce[{k (Cos[y] Sin[x] - Cos[x] Sin[y]) - Sin[x] == 0 && 
   k (-Cos[y] Sin[x] + Cos[x] Sin[y]) - Sin[y] == 0 && 
   0 <= x <= 2 \[Pi] && -2 \[Pi] <= y <= 0}, {x, y}, Reals]//FullSimplfy
```

[image]

Comment: Running time is very long, stopped after a few minutes when did not converge.

Comment: See my edit....